# Compile to Mono from Visual studio 2013

Tags: mono, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual studio 2013 and I'm want to compile my project for linux (with MONO).

Is this possible to use VS2013 (with or without mono plugin) to compile my project to MONO file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll be fine to use VS to build a .NET project that can run against Mono.

You'll be fine with the stock `csc` compiler and MSBuild (as both `csc` and the Mono compiler generate CIL all the same) just make sure that your project references Mono's assemblies rather than .NET's where there are breaking differences (e.g. System.Windows.Forms, etc). If you're doing ASP.NET or Console applications you should be fine without doing anything special.

Comment: Everything is working good for me, except, Entity Framework (version 6). Therefor, I'm leaving mono... I'll come back when its will be ready for me :)

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever, currently mono blends well with EF6, check out this [tutorial](http://www.davidloo.com/?p=519) on this topic...

Answer (score 2):

As long as you use the versions of the DLLs that come from nuget instead of the references that are added by default by Visual Studio you should be fine, provided you recompile everything with `xbuild`.

At the moment there are some minor differences in the CIL that is outputted by `msbuild` and what the mono VM can run.

Just run `xbuild` in the root directory of your solution or project. It will detect the `.sln`/`.proj` file and build everything.